# Extracting a sub array from an array of switches with Verilog?

Tags: verilog, intel-fpga

I am working with a Cyclone board. A basic code to assign every switch to the red leds is:

```
module part2 (SW, LEDR, LEDG);

    input [17:0] SW;    
    output [17:0] LEDR;

    assign LEDR = SW;

endmodule
```

But I need the value of SW[17] to do some output operations, I don't understand how to store it in an subarray... (I also need the inputs of SW[7:0] and SW[15:8] ). How can I achieve this?

I just started with Verilog today and I am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the slice operator.  You can read up on verilog in lots of places to get more details.   [Here's](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/veritut.html) a decent one.

Here's just an idea of some of the things you can do.  Read the tutorial at the link for more info.

```
module part2 (SW, LEDR, LEDG, SINGLE_BIT_OUT, ANOTHER_ARRAY_OUT, REGISTERED_OUT);

  input [17:0] SW;    
  output [17:0] LEDR;
  output SINGLE_BIT_OUT;           // This is one bit.
  output [2:0] ANOTHER_ARRAY_OUT;  // This is 3 bits.
  output reg [3:0] REGISTERED_OUT; // A 4 bit registered output.

  assign LEDR = SW; 
  assign SINGLE_BIT_OUT = SW[17];       // Continuous 1 bit assignment.
  assign ANOTHER_ARRAY_OUT = SW[11:9];  // Continuous 3 bit assignment.

  // Or you can use an always block to do more fancy stuff
  always @(SW) begin
      if (SW[2:0] == 2'b000)
         REGISTERED_OUT = 4'b0010;  // Just put a constant to it in this case.
      else
         REGISTERED_OUT = {1'b0, SW[2:0]};  // Or you can build assignments with slices like this.
  end

endmodule
```

Comment: How do I represent "If SW[17] is turned off"?

Comment: if (~SW [17]) ...

Comment: For a single bit, they are actually equivalent. For wider slices, not so much. ~ is bitwise inversion. ! is logical not.

Comment: Can you please answer here? I have a more specific issue. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/149711/how-do-for-loops-work-in-verylog-why-cant-i-achieve-what-i-want